# Where are these routes names set in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6

Netbeans isn't showing where the `Auth::routes();` is, ctrl+clicking on it, and I'm trying to see why this

`<a href="{{ route('register') }}">`

works but my own route in web.php does not work. Where is this file setting these? I assume this is a more proper way to set the url because /mynameroute could possibly not work if sites were within some sub directory in different environments?

Comment: a more proper way to set what URL? it knows what the URL is because your webserver is telling it what the host is

Comment: more proper than href="/whatever"

Comment: yea you use the URL helpers the framework comes with you can find them here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls ... there is a lot in the documentation but it is good to get acquainted with the structure and what the documentation goes into even if it is just a quick glance to get a very rough idea of what is offered to you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `Auth::routes()` is declared or works from `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` files's `auth()` method you can see there

```php
public function auth()
    {
        // Authentication Routes...
        $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
        $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        // Registration Routes...
        $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
        $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

        // Password Reset Routes...
        $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
        $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
    }
```

Comment: That's it, ->name(name). Thanks. How did you find this one?

Answer (score 1):

`Auth::routes()` is `Route::auth()` which is `Illuminate\Routing\Router@auth`. It isn't setting these routes in any special way; you could define them yourself if you wanted to.

For generating URLs there are multiple functions you can use depending on what you need:

[Laravel 6.x Docs - URL Generation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/urls)